# HaProxy - Read routing rules from external source

Tags: configuration, haproxy

I wonder if its possible for HaProxy to fetch configuration by doing "external" API-calls on startup? Scenario is if routing rules is managed/stored in other master system and HaProxy must include those. Would be nice if you were able to make API-call and put response as a *.map file or similar

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!